# How to apply when I press the button icon on the navigator the modal will automatically popup using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have face a problem, I have module where If i press the check icon on the navigation header the modal that i set as function will automatically popup. my programming language that I use is react native. and I used react-native library for the modal, lastly react-navigation for creating navigation of screens.

**My Goal: When I press the check icon on the top of header the modal automatically will open on the screen.**

[image: Check Icon]

Here is my function:

```
PrivacyShow() {
    <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    visible={true}
    onRequestClose={() => {
        alert('Modal has been closed.');
    }}>
    <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <View>
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
            }}>
            <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </View>
    </Modal>
}
```

Here is my render screens:

```
    class Navigator extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    PrivacyShow() {
        <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={true}
        onRequestClose={() => {
            alert('Modal has been closed.');
        }}>
        <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
            <View>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
        </Modal>
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Screen 
                        name="Registration" 
                        component={Register} 
                        options={{
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                            },
                            headerTitleStyle: {
                                color: '#fff',
                            },
                            headerTintColor:'#fff',
                            headerRight: () => (
                                // <Icon name="check" size={20} color="#ffff" />
                                <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "flex-end",paddingRight:10,width: 120}}>
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.PrivacyShow()}
                                    >
                                    <Icon type="font-awesome" name="check" size={20} color="white" />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            ),
                        }}
                   />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }

}

export default Navigator;
```

Comment: Side note: react-native **isn't** a programming language while `Javascript` is.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze thank you for side comment

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution for this:

1. I set Modal Visible false
2. When I press the button the false boolean will be on true

Here is the complete code:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import Register from '../screens/Register';
import PrivacyPolicy from '../screens/PrivacyPolicy';
import {Button,TouchableOpacity,View,Modal,Text, Alert, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {Overlay} from 'react-native-elements';
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class Navigator extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            modalVisible: false
        }
    }

    setModalVisible = (visible) => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    PrivacyModalShow() {
        const { modalVisible } = this.state;

        return (
        <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(false);
            }}
            >
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                        <View style={styles.modalView}>

                            <Text style={styles.modalText}>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac enim odio. Curabitur at dui a velit bibendum aliquet. Suspendisse elit erat, posuere eget tellus eget, maximus tristique sapien. Integer ornare erat a turpis aliquam, et scelerisque metus congue. Nulla turpis ante, rutrum ac massa egestas, ultrices blandit est. Etiam lectus nisl, viverra vel gravida quis, lacinia nec sapien. Etiam eu facilisis leo. Duis ac aliquam ante. Donec vel velit ipsum. Morbi tempor erat consectetur, aliquet augue nec,
                                tristique nibh. In hendrerit sem non aliquet convallis. Donec molestie mauris sit amet quam posuere euismod.
                            </Text>

                            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                                <CheckBox
                                />
                                <Text style={styles.label}>I have read and agree to the <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Policy')} style={{textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#4ABDFF', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:17}}>terms and condition and data privacy policy</Text></Text>
                            </View>

                            <View style={styles.confirmationContainer}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:17,textAlign:"right",flex:1, fontWeight:'bold'}} onPress={() => {
                                this.setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}>No</Text>
                                <Text style={{marginLeft:30,fontSize:17,textAlign:"right",  color:'#4ABDFF', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Yes, Agree</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </Modal>
        )
    }

    render() {        
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
               
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Login" 
                            component={Login} 
                            options={{
                                headerShown: false,
                            }}
                        />

                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Registration" 
                            component={Register} 
                            options={{
                                headerStyle: {
                                    backgroundColor: '#4ABDFF'
                                },
                                headerTitleStyle: {
                                    color: '#fff',
                                },
                                headerTintColor:'#fff',
                                headerRight: () => (
                                    <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "flex-end",paddingRight:10,width: 120}}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true) }
                                        >
                                        <Icon type="font-awesome" name="check" size={20} color="white" />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                ),
                            }}
                        
                        />

                        <Stack.Screen 
                            name="Policy" 
                            component={PrivacyPolicy} 
                            options={{
                                headerShown: false,
                            }}
                        />
                </Stack.Navigator>
                {this.PrivacyModalShow()}
            </NavigationContainer>
            
        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    centeredView: {
      marginTop: 22,
      width:'100%'

    },
    checkboxContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginBottom: 0,
    },
    confirmationContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    label: {
        margin: 6,
        fontSize:17
    },
    confirmationLabel: {
        
        fontSize:17,
        textAlign:'right',
        flex:1
    },
    modalView: {
      margin: 30,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 5,
      padding: 35,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 5,
      maxWidth:'100%'
    },
    textStyle: {
      color: "white",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    modalText: {
      marginBottom: 5,
      fontSize:17,
    }
});
  

export default Navigator;
```